# Sorting and copying files

Tags: files, file-copy

I am newbie here, please be patient.

I have a directory containing thousands of files. Filename always start with 1 or 2 letter and have 4 character before underscore "_". The number of files for each pattern can be different, the part of file name after underscore changes.

Sample:

```
Parentdir:
->AA01_*.pdf 
->AA01_*.html
->AA01_*.txt
...
->ZZ99_*.pdf
->ZZ99_*.html
->ZZ99_*.txt
...
->A001_*.pdf
->A001_*.html
->A001_*.txt
...
->Z999_*.pdf
->Z999_*.html
->Z999_*.txt
```

I would like to run a command that would create new directories using only letters from file-name and populate them with files starting with these letters.
If there is a file with the same name in the destination directory (updated file in the source dir), I'd like to keep most recent one. so:

```
New dir/files:
->AA
  AA01_*.pdf
  AA01_*.html
  AA01_*.txt
...
->ZZ
  ZZ99_*.pdf
  ZZ99_*.html
  ZZ99_*.txt
...
->A
  A001_*.pdf
  A001_*.html
  A001_*.txt
...
->Z
  Z999_*.pdf
  Z999_*.html
  Z999_*.txt
```

Can this be accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: `A1001_*.txt` in your example output isn't in your sample input and does not match your stated filename spec.   Is it OK to assume you want to match files starting with one-or-two word characters, followed by at least 2 digits and then an underscore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop across the set of files. Pick off the alphabetic prefix. Create the directory (if necessary) and move the file into it.

```
#!/bin/sh
for item in *
do
    if [ -f "$item" ]
    then
        prefix="$(echo "$item" | sed 's/[^A-Z].*//')"
        echo mkdir -p "$prefix"
        echo mv "$item" "$prefix/"
    fi
done
```

Remove the `echo` prefixes from `mkdir` and `mv` when you're happy it's going to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using the **perl** `rename` utility (aka `prename`, `file-rename`, `perl-rename` on some linux distributions):

```
rename  -n  'if (m/^(\w{1,2}?)(\d{2,}_.*)/) {mkdir $1; $_ = "$1/$1$2"}' *
```

NOTE: this works **ONLY** with the perl-based rename utility.  You can check if you have it installed by running `rename -V` (or `prename -V` or `file-rename -V` or `perl-rename -V`).  If that mentions perl or `File::Rename`, then it's the perl version of `rename`.  Otherwise, it's probably the `rename` from `util-linux` which has completely different and **incompatible** features and command-line options.   This will **NOT** work with util-linux's rename (or any other version of rename - it **requires** perl rename)

This uses the first one or two "word" characters (non-greedy match) of each matching filename as the directory, then creates the directory, and renames the file into the directory.   A "word" character (`\w`) is defined in `man perlre` as:

> "Match a "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_", plus
> other connector punctuation chars plus Unicode marks)"

If this isn't precisely what you want, you can refine the pattern by using, e.g. `[[:alpha:]]{1,2}?` instead of `\w{1,2}?` for any alphabetic characters, or `[[:upper:]]{1,2}` for upper-case only characters.

The `\d` matches digits only.  If you want to allow **any** word characters before the underscore, use `\w`.   Or use `[[:alnum:]]` if you want to allow alphabetic and digit characters only.

Filenames that do not match the entire pattern (1-or-2 "word" characters, followed by at least two digits, followed by an underscore) are unaffected.

Note: the `-n` option makes this a dry-run operation.  It will only show what it **would** do, without actually doing it.  Once you're sure that it does what you want, remove the `-n` (or replace it with `-v` for verbose output).

e.g. given the following setup script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for i in A AA Z9 ZZ  ; do
  for j in {01..10} ; do
    touch "$i${j}_.txt"
  done
done

# anomaly
touch A1001_.txt
```

```
$ ./setup.sh
$ ls
A01_.txt  A02_.txt  A03_.txt A04_.txt  A05_.txt  A06_.txt  A07_.txt  A08_.txt
A09_.txt A1001_.txt A10_.txt AA01_.txt AA02_.txt AA03_.txt AA04_.txt AA05_.txt
AA06_.txt AA07_.txt AA08_.txt AA09_.txt AA10_.txt setup.sh* Z901_.txt
Z902_.txt Z903_.txt Z904_.txt Z905_.txt Z906_.txt Z907_.txt Z908_.txt
Z909_.txt Z910_.txt ZZ01_.txt ZZ02_.txt ZZ03_.txt ZZ04_.txt ZZ05_.txt
ZZ06_.txt ZZ07_.txt ZZ08_.txt ZZ09_.txt ZZ10_.txt
```

After running the perl rename script:

```
$ rename 'if (m/^(\w{1,2}?)(\d{2,}_.*)/) {mkdir $1; $_ = "$1/$1$2"}' *
$ ls */*
A/A01_.txt   A/A02_.txt   A/A03_.txt   A/A04_.txt   A/A05_.txt A/A06_.txt
A/A07_.txt   A/A08_.txt   A/A09_.txt   A/A1001_.txt A/A10_.txt AA/AA01_.txt
AA/AA02_.txt AA/AA03_.txt AA/AA04_.txt AA/AA05_.txt AA/AA06_.txt
AA/AA07_.txt AA/AA08_.txt AA/AA09_.txt AA/AA10_.txt Z/Z901_.txt
Z/Z902_.txt  Z/Z903_.txt  Z/Z904_.txt  Z/Z905_.txt  Z/Z906_.txt  Z/Z907_.txt
Z/Z908_.txt  Z/Z909_.txt  Z/Z910_.txt ZZ/ZZ01_.txt ZZ/ZZ02_.txt ZZ/ZZ03_.txt
ZZ/ZZ04_.txt ZZ/ZZ05_.txt ZZ/ZZ06_.txt ZZ/ZZ07_.txt ZZ/ZZ08_.txt
ZZ/ZZ09_.txt ZZ/ZZ10_.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the forums, Zica!

I'd like to suggest [`organize`](https://github.com/tfeldmann/organize) - if you have some patience, you can create a script in `yaml` that can search for files in given locations, rename, move, sort, you name it! I use it myself. I do not know what your proficiency is in Linux, but the Git has a readthedocs which explains everything you need in a very easy to understand way.

Comment: An example would be helpful, to show the OP how to use it to solve their requirement